# Convert auto (string) to char in D

Tags: d

For iterate with foreach loop and get dates over the files I need to have as input char [], but not string.

I wrote next code:

```
auto files = dirEntries ("E:\\ddd", SpanMode.shallow);

foreach (file; files)
{
    char [] s = to!char[](file); //it's crap... and do not work...
    writeln(file);

}
```

I use next method http://dlang.org/phobos/std_file.html#.getTimes
it's need as input char []: (in char[] name)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a mutable copy of immutable array you may use `.dup`:

```
char[] s = file.dup;
```

However in your case you don't need to do any conversion. `getTimes` accepts `in char[]` which is shortcut for `scope const char[]`. It it perfectly legal to pass immutable arrays as const arguments so it should "just work".

Comment: thanks, that's work!

But now I am getting error on this code:
https://codeo.me/3nP
Error: recursive opCmp expansion

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion line should look like:

```
... = to!(char[])(file.name);
```

This is because the shorthand template instantiation isn't valid for multiple tokens.

Second, there should be no need to convert to char[], as you said getTimes takes an "in char[]" which means it will not modify the string which means the immutable(char)[] can be passed without conversion.

Answer (score -3):

You can also use :

```
const char[] s = cast(char[]) file;
```

Comment: You don't need cast for that (const can reference immutable). And please don't recommend to use qualifier casts in user code - it is an advanced tool that may completely break type system, should only be used by those who really know what they are doing.